# Configuring systemd to manage a service on boot

Tags: 18.04, bash, python, systemd

I have a script that downloads an image from a web page and sets it as my desktop wallpaper. The code works fine but I am having trouble getting it to run on boot.

I am trying to do this by configuring systemd to manage a service. (crontab didn't work for me when rebooting but that's another issue).

I made a file `/etc/systemd/system/apod.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set APOD as Desktop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/me/apod.sh
Type=simple
User=me
Group=me
WorkingDirectory=/home/me
Restart=on-failure
```

But when I boot it doesn't seem to work. If I check `systemctl status apod`, I see:

```
Jun 04 20:55:55 me-XPS-15-9500 systemd[1]: Started Set APOD as Desktop.
Jun 04 20:55:57 me-XPS-15-9500 gsettings[1598]: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

Yet if I just manually run `/bin/bash /home/me/apod.sh` then it works perfectly.

Any suggestions welcome. I'm running 18.04.

---

For completeness:

The bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                 

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus"

python /home/me/apod.py

/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/me/Downloads/apod.jpg"
```

The python script it calls:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
import requests
import subprocess
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen('https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html')
soup = BSHTML(page,features="html.parser")
images = soup.findAll('img')

url = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/'+images[0]['src']
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
with open('/home/me/Downloads/apod.jpg',"w") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: It seems to me that you'd want this to run as a --user service when you log in, not as a system service when the OS reboots?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer that question :) The only reason I was trying to do it via a system service is because someone advised that. I'm happy to investigate other ways though!

Comment: When you boot and login is the image `apod.jpg` there in the Downloads, and when you run `python /home/me/apod.py` does it successfully save the image to Downloads folder ?

Comment: I just checked and it seems like the photo didn't download. So perhaps it's the download step that is failing for some reason. But to be clear, if I run the script manually the download and everything works perfectly, so it's not an issue with the downloading code / process itself.

Comment: I'm just noticing that when I change the `apod.jpg` manually, the desktop background changes to reflect the new image instantaneously! Is it my `systemd` script that is doing this?

Comment: You could schedule a cronjob using anacron to run this script daily. If your computer is shutdown, anacron will make sure to run the script whenever your computer is back online.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change background in a system boot script because your graphical environment isn't started yet.  I'd suggest adding your script to your startup applications in gnome-tweaks.

There's actually two parts to this.

One is the gsettings change you are making -- which is actually permanent and doesn't need to be repeated unless something else is changing it and you want to reset it, or if you want to change the filename.

The other is downloading the image, and if you replace the file rather than using a new name, it may change instantly.

The download also likely fails at boot because the network may not be fully up when it runs, despite the network-online.target dependency.  Fixing this would delay the system booting -- this would probably also be better done during login startup instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a similar system, so you should be able to get it working with systemd. You can include a systemd timer along with your service file to trigger the service to run at boot after you login. Since root priviledges aren't required for setting a wallpaper, you can do as @Jeff Schaller suggested and create a systemd user service. You can store your systemd user files in `$HOME/.config/systemd/user`

You can modify the apod.service file to something like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set APOD as Desktop
After=network.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=network-online.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/me/apod.sh
```

Add a file called apod.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for apod.service

[Timer]
OnBootSec=0 min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Place `apod.service` and `apod.timer` in `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/`
and enable them like normal, but instead of using root privileges/invoking sudo, do so as a normal user and add the `--user` flag to the command:

`systemctl --user enable apod.timer`

`systemctl --user enable apod.service`

Edit: It also appears that the 'image' of the day for today's date from linked nasa source is a video, so that could be something to watch out for.

Edit2: left off enabling the `.service` in addition to the `.timer`

Answer (score -1):

As you said it is working by executing it manually, I think you should choose a different way via crontab.

execute: 
`sudo crontab -e`
then add a line at the end like this
`@reboot /bin/bash /home/me/apod.sh`

reboot and see if it works.

you can also change @reboot which will run only once after boot for something hourly or so (see cron manual).

Something like this (in crontab) will be hourly.

`0 * * * * /bin/bash /home/me/apod.sh`

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: That likely won't work because networking won't be up yet and the GUI session won't be up yet and the cron job doesn't have access to the GUI session by default anyway.